# Can I find out which button created an event in my Trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger

I am playing around with a trigger that will send out my own custom emails when someone creates/updates an event using the Salesforce UI.

So far, I have found to look at the url to differentiate between a UI and API call.

UI Save (new):

```
url:[delegate=https://tdahle-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/00u/e]
```

UI Save (Update):

```
url:[delegate=https://tdahle-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/00u4100000bmv82/e]
```

UI Save and send update (Update):

```
url:[delegate=https://tdahle-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/00u4100000bmv82/e]
```

API Save/Update:

```
url:[delegate=https://tdahle-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/apexremote]
```

So, looking for /apexremote, I can tell if it is an API or UI call, but is there anyway to tell if Save or Save And Send Update was pressed to create the event? Obviously looking at the URL won't solve that issue.

Comment: URL detection is not reliable in all situations. What if someone uses the SOAP API? What if someone uses the REST API? What if someone uses the Bulk API? What if someone uses a Scheduled class? There's no way to consistent way to distinguish between all of the possible actions where a record might be created or updated. `/apexremote/`, by the way, is only one of the possible API endpoints...

Comment: True, I did forget, I will be changing it from looking for /apexremote to UI endings. I just have not done that quite yet. But the trigger may be scrapped entirely if I cannot differentiate between which button was clicked. Users would expect the emails to only go out if Save And Send Update was clicked, not if just Save was.